# Intersection area of 2 polygons in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, geometry, polygons

I have the contours of 2 polygons (as vector of cv::Point2d).

I would like to calculate the area of intersection between them

What is the easiest way to get it?

Thank you very much!

Ron

Answer (score 12):

Draw the shapes with `CV_FILLED` in two images and AND them. Area is:  `CountNonZero(bitwise_and(ShapeAImage,ShapeBImage))`.

Answer (score 4):

You can find intersection polygon wth [Clipper library](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php)

```
//create clipper polygons from your points
c.AddPolygons(subj, ptSubject);
c.AddPolygons(clip, ptClip);
c.Execute(ctIntersection, solution, pftNonZero, pftNonZero);
```

then [calc area of this polygon](http://alienryderflex.com/polygon_area/)

Comment: [`contourArea()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga2c759ed9f497d4a618048a2f56dc97f1) from OpenCV can also calculate area of polygon

Comment: @n0099 But we have to get intersection first - much more complex problem

Comment: [`cv::intersectConvexConvex()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga06eed475945f155030f2135a7f25f11d) can calculate the intersection polygon and its area if the two input polygons are [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polygon).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest method to code goes like this:

```
cv::Rect BoundingBox;
int IntersectionArea = 0;
//insert Min-Max X,Y to create the BoundingBox

for (every y inside boundingbox)
     for (every x inside boundingbox)
         if (PointPolygonTest(x,y,Contour1) && PointPolygonTest(x,y,Contour2))
             IntersectionArea++;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't help me because I need is to be more accurate then using a bounding box... The polygons can be in wierd shapes (L shape for example) and bounding box just can't handle those cases. Thank you any way!

Comment: It IS accurate. The bounding box is used as optimization to reduce the number of pixels that are tested for being inside both polygons. Technically you can do every "x" and every "y" in the image, and it would produce the same results.

Comment: This solution would be very slow.